# Java how can I with reflection check if a field is initialized or is default value?

Tags: java, reflection

So, should be straight forward question.

Lets say I have a class with a lot of fields like:

```
String thizz;
long that;
boolean bar;
```

How can I, with reflection, see if the fields `thizz`, `that` and `bar` have been initialized or left to their default values of null, 0 and false?

Comment: why is reflection necessary? Can't you just check them?

Comment: Because I dont know how many and what fields the other object has, it changes a lot...

Comment: Please note that the default value of `Boolean` is `null`. Perhaps you had `boolean` in mind?

Comment: Wait, so are you asking how to dynamically look up an object's fields and values? That's kind of a different question.

Comment: This is the default values for java types: http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/datatypes.html

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You have only 7 primitive types and one reference type to check.  If you group all Number types together, you only have four values to check for.

```
Object o =
for (Field field : o.getClass().getDeclaredFields()) {
 Class t = field.getType();
 Object v = field.get(o);
 if(t == boolean.class && Boolean.FALSE.equals(v)) 
   // found default value
 else if(t == char.class && ((Character) v).charValue() == 0)
   // found default value
 else if(t.isPrimitive() && ((Number) v).doubleValue() == 0)
   // found default value
 else if(v == null)
   // found default value
}
```

Comment: @Rahul that's what the checks in the middle of the code are for, yes.

Comment: What about `char`? (`Character` is not a `Number`)

Comment: @DodgyCodeException a `char` is an unsigned 16-bit value. e.g. you can write `char ch = 48;` or `Character ch = 48;` or `char ch = '0'; ch /= 0.9;` It is `0` or `'\0'` before initialisation.

Comment: @PeterLawrey yes but even so, you'll still get a ClassCastException in `else if(t.isPrimitive() && ((Number) v).doubleValue() == 0)` because v is of class Character, which is not castable to Number.

Comment: @DodgyCodeException Thank you for the correction. I have added this case.

Answer (score 8):

[Peter Lawrey's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7224331/4173303) works fine for me, except for fields of primitive data type `char`, which raises the following exception in my code :

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.Character cannot be cast to java.lang.Number
```

So I added the `char` case :

```
Object o =
for (Field field : o.getClass().getDeclaredFields()) {
 Class t = field.getType();
 Object v = field.get(o);
 if (boolean.class.equals(t) && Boolean.FALSE.equals(v)) 
   // found default value
 else if (char.class.equals(t) && ((Character) v) != Character.MIN_VALUE)
   // found default value
 else if (t.isPrimitive() && ((Number) v).doubleValue() == 0)
   // found default value
 else if(!t.isPrimitive() && v == null)
   // found default value
}
```

`Character.MIN_VALUE` is `'\u0000'`, which is the default value of `char` according to the [Java Documentation on primitive data types](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/datatypes.html).

Comment: It's helpful. Thanks!

Answer (score 6):

You don't need reflection...

```
if (thizz == null) {
    //it's not initialized
}
if (that == 0) {
   //it's not initialized
}
if(bar == false) {
    //it's not initialized
}
```

However, they could have been initialized then reset to their default values. If you truly want to know if they're been initialized you could do something like this:

```
private boolean isFooInitialized = false;
private Foo foo;
public void setFoo(Foo foo) {
    this.foo = foo;
    isFooInitialized = foo != null;
}
```

/edit
To get all the fields from a class, check out [Class.getDeclaredFields()](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getDeclaredFields()). This will give every field, not just the public ones.

From here you can check the type of the field and get its value:

```
Foo foo = ...
Field[] fooFields = foo.getClass().getDeclaredFields();
for (Field fooField : fooFields) {
    Class<?> fooFieldClass = fooField.getClass();
    if (fooFieldClass.equals(int.class)) {
        if (fooField.getInt(foo) == 0) {
            // not initialized
        }
    } else if (fooFieldClass.equals(double.class)) {
        if (fooField.getDouble(foo) == 0) {
            // not initialized
        }
    } else if (fooFieldClass.equals(boolean.class)) {
        if (fooField.getBoolean(foo) == false) {
            // not initialized
        }
    } else if (fooFieldClass.equals(float.class)) {
        if (fooField.getFloat(foo) == 0) {
            // not initialized
        }
    } else if (fooFieldClass.equals(char.class)) {
        if (fooField.getChar(foo) == 0) {
            // not initialized
        }
    } else if (fooFieldClass.equals(byte.class)) {
        if (fooField.getByte(foo) == 0) {
            // not initialized
        }
    } else if (fooFieldClass.equals(long.class)) {
        if (fooField.getLong(foo) == 0) {
            // not initialized
        }
    } else if (fooField.get(foo) == null) {
        // not initialized
    }
}
```

Comment: Ah, let me restate my question, I actually dont care if the value has been initialized and later set to null or 0, I just need to check the default for all Javas possible types, primitives as well as java.lang objects

Comment: @AntonioP In that case, it's easy -- there are only ~7 (I could be wrong by one or two) different "default values". One for each primitive and one for non-primitives. A simple overloaded method could easily perform the check: `bool IsDefault(bool b)`, `bool IsDefault(long i)`, etc (some types can be doubled up, like `int/long` and `float/double`), modify for reflection as/if required.

Comment: @Jeffrey, Yeah that was kind of what I did, except I used to check instance of Number, Boolean and String, the rest I assume are false anyway...

Comment: @AntonioP If you already did this, where's the problem with it?

Comment: I did it like this after I asked my question since I figured I could try it and it worked, but still there might be a smarter way of doing it :) I thought there would be a way to ask an object are you null false or 0 without doing instanceof on its value for different types

Comment: @AntionoP Ahh, I don't think there's a better way of doing this. Cheers.

Comment: @Jeffrey, Most of the values can be compared with 0, you don't need so many checks. See my answer.

Comment: @Peter Lawrey I guess I was just being thorough. That would be a much better way to go about this.

Answer (score 6):

You can create a new instance via reflection (automatically initialized with default value) and compare yourObject with this default instance.

```
//default Object filled with default values:
Object defaultObject = yourObject.getClass().newInstance();
for (final Field field : yourObject.getClass().getDeclaredFields()) {
  final Object value = field.get(yourObject);
  if (value == null || value.equals(field.get(defaultObject))) {
    // found default value
  }
}
```

PS: This solution also solved the issue with char mentioned by Christophe Weis.

Comment: This solution should have more upvotes. If you create the default object without a static type you do not even have to depend on `Foo`.
Do it this way: `Object defaultObject = yourObject.getClass().newInstance();` (this can be even more refined if you get all the constructors and create one that has the least parameters).

Comment: This will throw an java.lang.NoSuchMethodException for class that does not have a default constructor, like Integer for example.

Answer (score 1):

This should get you going in the right direction.

```
    Class clazz = Class.forName("your.class");
    Field[] fields = clazz.getDeclaredFields();
    for (Field field : fields) {
      String dataType = field.getType().getName();
      if (dataType.equals("java.lang.String")) {
          System.out.println("found a string");
      }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

The gist of it is:

```
Field[] fields = yourObject.getClass().getFields();
for(Field f : fields)
{
  Class<?> k = f.getType();
  // depending on k, methods like f.getInt(yourObject),
  // f.getFloat(yourObject), 
  // f.getObject(hourObject) to get each member.
}
```

Now, this only lets you read the public fields.

Alternatively, IF your object follows getX/setX naming conventions, you can use getMethods(), and look for methods named "getXxx" and "setXxx", to infer the existence of settable fields -- and invoke those getters to look for the expected default values.

Comment: Note that `getFields()` only returns public fields.

Comment: `getDeclaredFields()` gives you all fields.