# Is there any way of calling sequential variable name in java in a for loop?

Tags: java, variables

Is there any way of calling sequential variable name in java in a for loop like matlab? For example I have variable names like c11,c12,c13... Is there any way i can call them in a for loop as they have c in common and after that the name parts are sequential?

Comment: That's not the way to do it... Put the elements in a list and iterate them.

Comment: That's what arrays or lists are made for.

Comment: Do you want maybe a dictionary-like data structure, such as HashMap?

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17095628/loop-over-all-fields-in-a-java-class.

Comment: For this reason you should use Array or ArrayList whichever is compatible or useful according to your need. Just Assign an Array with some variable name let's call **c** and then iterate in the loop with **c[position]**. This will work as like what you are dealing with.

Comment: Thanks a lot..for the response. But i need to take input from 81 JtextFields which are named like these. Thats why ineeded that. Thanks a lot for your response.

Comment: Why are the JTextFields named like that? These fields could also be in an array.

Answer (score 0):

You can use reflection (see [`Class.getDeclaredField(String)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getDeclaredField(java.lang.String)):

```
MyTextFieldContainer container; // the object that contains the 81 JTextFields

Class<MyTextFieldContainer> containerType = container.getClass();

for (int 1 = 1; i <= 81; i++) {
    string fieldName = "textfield" + i.toString();
    Field fieldReflection = containerType.getDeclaredField(fieldName);
    Object fieldValue = fieldReflection.get(container);
    JTextField textfield = (JTextField)fieldValue;

    … // Use the JTextField however you like
}
```

Check the various method in `Class<T>` to select the one that fits your needs:

- `getDeclared…()` vs. `get…()`:

  - `getDeclared…()` returns and field/method/etc. that is declared in `containerType` (i.e. public, protected, and private), it does *not* return any inherited fields/methods/etc.;
  - `get…()` only retrieves public fields/methods/etc. both those declared in `containerType` and those inherited from base classes and interfaces.
- `get…Field()`, `get…Method()`, and `get…Constructor()`: return respectively fields, methods, and constructors.
- `get…s()` vs. `get…(String)`: `getFields()` and similar methods return an array of all fields (or methods or contructors) in the class; and `getField(String)` returns the named field, if it exists.

Comment: I do not recomment this method of accessing the JTextFields, but if you have to you can do it.  It's better to redesign your class that contains the 81 JTextFields.