# How to write an Iterator for a custom class in Java

Tags: java

I have this class:

```
public class MyClass{
   private Test test;

   public class Test{
     int num;
     String color;

     public Test(int num, String color){
     this.num = num;
     this.color = color;
     }
   }

   public MyClass(){

   }

   public void setNum(int number){
       test.num = number;
   }

   public void setColor(String color){
       test.color = color;
   }

   public Test getTest(){
       return test;
   }
}
```

I am setting the values from another class and at the end I call the method getTest:

```
MyClass myclass = new MyClass();
.
.    
.
Test test1 = myclass.getTest();
```

I want to Iterate the object test1 to get the values. Is that possible? Do I have to implement hasNext() method inside the class MyClass? If yes, how can I do it?

Comment: test1.num and test1.color

Comment: They're off different types - what are you actually trying to achieve here?  (i.e. what do you want to do with this hypothetical iterator?)

Comment: Why would you use an Iterator to do that? There's one int and one string. They're not conceptually a sequence. They're not even the same type! Just use `test1.num` and `test1.color`.

Comment: I know they are different types, that's why I need an answer. I am trying to save me time.

Comment: @user2357112  In my original code, I have 100 fields, not just 2.

Comment: @dirac: We can't give you a meaningful answer without *context*.  What is your goal here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You question has already been [asked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17095628/loop-over-all-fields-in-a-java-class) and answered.

Basic idea - you need to use reflection API . E.g construction `test.getClass().getDeclaredFields();`

Note: you will not create iterator this way, but you will be able to iterate through class fields. That slightly different things.

Answer (score 0):

You want this？

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    MyClass myclass = new MyClass();
    Test test1 = myclass.getTest();
    //you need modify private Test test = new Test(1, "hahs");
    //import java.lang.reflect.Field;
    Field[] fields = test1.getClass().getDeclaredFields();
    for (int j = 0; j < fields.length-1; j++) {
        fields[j].setAccessible(true);
        try {
            System.out.println(fields[j].get(test1));
        } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    //output
    //1
    //hahs
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You will have to use reflection in order to iterate through the members of the `test` class.  You will have to import `java.lang.reflect.*` and call `Class.forName("test1)` to get a Class object, and call the `getDeclaredFields` method of the Class object to get an array of Field objects.  The `Field` object has `get` and `set` methods that get or set the value of the field.