# Copying nested objects with references to each other

Tags: java, oracle

I have two tables in database having one to many relationship.
while I fetch the table User, I want to copy the data in the User (with the data related to Vehicle) to another object UserDuplicate (and VehicleDuplicate).
I tried using BeanUtils.copyProperties but the nested references still refer to old object.
I want to know what is the way to copy the nested objects.
Thanks.

```
import java.util.Set;


public class User {

    private Set<Vehicle> vehs = new HasHSet();

    public Set<Vehicle> getVehs() {
        return vehs;
    }

    public void setVehs(Set<Vehicle> vehs) {
        this.vehs = vehs;
    }
}

class Vehicle {

    private User user;

    public User getUser() {
        return user;
    }

    public void setUser(User user) {
        this.user = user;

    }
}

class UserDuplicate {

    private Set<VehicleDuplicate> vehDup=new HasHSet();

    public Set<VehicleDuplicate> getVehDup() {
        return vehDup;
    }

    public void setVehDup(Set<VehicleDuplicate> vehDup) {
        this.vehDup = vehDup;
    }   
}

class VehicleDuplicate {

    private UserDuplicate userDup;

    public UserDuplicate getUserDup() {
        return userDup;
    }

    public void setUserDup(UserDuplicate userDup) {
        this.userDup = userDup;
    }   
}
```

Comment: I don't understand why you have the _classes_ `VehicleDuplicate` and `UserDuplicate ` - they are **identical** to `Vehicle` and `User`; what possible purpose can they serve?

Comment: You have to create a recursive method to walk through the fields of your objects and call the clone method.  Further, every object must implements/override clone method for doing that.  **Loop over all fields in a Java class:** https://stackoverflow.com/a/17095665/1715121

Comment: we have an external data ingestion to the the table and I am writing a job to copy data from one table to another after proper cleanup.So I am copying data from stagging to application tables with more or less same schema.

Answer (score 0):

I like to use copy constructors in these cases:

```
class UserDuplicate {
```

...

```
UserDuplicate(User user) {
```

...

```
    if (user.getVehs() != null) {
        vehDup = new HashSet<>();
        for (Vehicle v: user.getVehs()) {
            vehDup.add(new VehicleDuplicate(this, v));
        }
    }
}
```

...

```
class VehicleDuplicate {
```

...

```
VehicleDuplicate(UserDuplicate userDup, Vehicle veh) {
    this.userDup = userDup;
```

...

```
}
```

Comment: I did the changes and called the constructor as :UserDuplicate u= new UserDuplicate(user); But I get UserDuplicate object containing vehileDuplicate field as an  empty arraylist.

Comment: @Aadil so what does it suggest to you?

Comment: @Aadil I can't help you there: my code obviously adds as many VehicleDuplicate as there are Vehicles. The problem is elsewhere...

Comment: Thankyou. I set the vehDup value inside constructor to the this object and it worked..  this.setVehDup(vehDup) thanks

Answer (score 0):

One approach could be to use a mapper to copy what you need to the duplicated object, this approach can have a lighter footprint on your code...

You can for example use [jackson-databind](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-databind)

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
mapper.configure(SerializationFeature.FAIL_ON_EMPTY_BEANS, false);
UserDuplicate duplicated = mapper.readValue(mapper.writeValueAsString(source), UserDuplicate.class);
// set the correct duplicate user in the duplicated vehicule
duplicated.getVehDup().forEach(x -> x.setUserDup(duplicated));
```

This will serialize the `source` object into JSON and then deserialize it into an instance of the `duplicated` object.

Because you are saying that your schemas are more or less the same you can take care of the annotations provided by Jackson for example to ignore some field.

```
static class User {

    @JsonIgnore // Allows to ignore attributes from stadging to production
    private String iDontWantToCopyThis = "blablabla";

    private Set<Vehicle> vehs;

    public Set<Vehicle> getVehs() {
        return vehs;
    }

    public void setVehs(Set<Vehicle> vehs) {
        this.vehs = vehs;
    }
}
```

Doing this the `iDontWantToCopyThis` field won't be copied into the duplicated object.

Because your `Vehicle` contains a reference to the `user` you need to annotate with `@JsonIgnore` to avoid the recursivity during the deserialization.

```
static class Vehicle {

    @JsonIgnore 
    private User user;

    public User getUser() {
        return user;
    }

    public void setUser(User user) {
        this.user = user;

    }
}
```

And because the name of the vehicule set is different into the `UserDuplicate` class you must use the annotation `@JsonProperty("vehs")` to let the mapper know how to match the datas.

```
 static class UserDuplicate {

    @JsonProperty("vehs") // need to specify the source name into the json used to load the user duplicated
    private Set<VehicleDuplicate> vehDup;

    public Set<VehicleDuplicate> getVehDup() {
        return vehDup;
    }

    public void setVehDup(Set<VehicleDuplicate> vehDup) {
        this.vehDup = vehDup;
    }   
}
```

If you have data transformations too complex to be processed just by the annotations you can also create custom serializer or deserializer...